# Cannot boot into Ubuntu 22.04 from Grub after accident w/ laptop

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

So I have an Ubuntu + Windows 10 dual boot on my Acer Aspire ES1-572-33BP. After my laptop fell to the ground, everything seemed to be working properly, but, after shutting Ubuntu down, I couldn't boot into it again. [The error looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeRPA.jpg)

Since I left my Ubuntu LiveUSB home, I installed smartmantools into my Windows 10 partition and ran `systemctl -a /dev/sda` to see what happened. The output is as follows:

```
> smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-w10-22H2] (sf-7.4-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    17G8C4RZT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 7836863cb
Firmware Version: AX1P5J
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Aug 18 17:44:14 2023 HB
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 243) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1688
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30237
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   068   068   000    Old_age   Always       -       13089
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   253   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5420
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       305
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       1945
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       85597
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 13/53)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       224
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   073   073   000    Old_age   Always       -       10932
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       177
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 149 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 149 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13088 hours (545 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 a8 90 65 51 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00516590 = 5334416

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 a8 90 65 51 40 00      00:03:27.386  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:27.386  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:27.385  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:27.384  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:03:27.384  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 148 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13088 hours (545 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 08 90 65 51 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00516590 = 5334416

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 08 90 65 51 40 00      00:03:23.534  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 f8 58 cb f3 40 00      00:03:23.534  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:23.533  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:23.533  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:23.532  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 147 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13088 hours (545 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 70 90 65 51 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00516590 = 5334416

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 18 b0 40 cb f3 40 00      00:03:21.053  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 70 90 65 51 40 00      00:03:19.696  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:19.670  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 08 88 38 cb f3 40 00      00:03:19.670  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:19.670  FLUSH CACHE EXT

Error 146 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13088 hours (545 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 20 90 65 51 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00516590 = 5334416

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 18 28 20 cb f3 40 00      00:03:15.813  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 20 90 65 51 40 00      00:03:15.813  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:15.813  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:15.812  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:15.812  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 145 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13088 hours (545 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 38 90 65 51 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00516590 = 5334416

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 38 90 65 51 40 00      00:03:11.973  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 18 18 cb f3 40 00      00:03:11.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:11.973  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:11.972  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:11.972  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13088         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

So I don't know if my HDD has been damaged, since GRUB and Windows 10 are still working just fine. Has the damage only affected Ubuntu, and, if it did, is it possible to fix it? Is booting to Windows 10 from my HDD still safe?

Comment: I would recommend immediately to backup all your data.
The important question is if it fall while running or when it wasn't?

Comment: @Mlocik97 yes, it did fall while it was running. Also worth mentioning that it did not shut down after falling, and I could no longer access Ubuntu only after I turned the laptop off.